# Why does OnAppearing not fire every time in Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a Xamarin project. When I run in UWP `OnAppearing` initially fires once and then loads the Login Page. After successfully logging in, my Main page fires `OnAppearing` again and I load data into my ViewModel.

However, if I run the project in Android, `OnAppearing` only fires once - When the Main page initially loads.

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    if (!App.IsUserLoggedIn)
    {
        await App.NavigationService.NavigateModalAsync(PageNames.LoginPage, false);
    }
    else
    {
        ((SchedulerViewModel)Schedule.BindingContext).LoadData();
    }

    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

Why does Android only fire once? Or is UWP the one misbehaving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: `NavigationService` is not a standard Xamarin Forms class. I assume it is built on top of Page.Navigation.PushModalAsync and PopModalAsync.

---

This is documented behavior of Modal Stack on Android:

[Popping Pages from the Modal Stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/modal#popping-pages-from-the-modal-stack):

> When PopModalAsync is invoked, the following events occur:
> ...
> The page being returned to has its OnAppearing override invoked, **provided that the underlying platform isn't Android.**

NOTE: it seems to depend on the API version of Android. I just tested it on API 30, and Android **did** fire OnAppearing again, when modal page was popped.

---

Instead of code in OnAppearing, I would solve it like this:

In `App.xaml.cs`, instead of:

```cs
MainPage = new MainPage();
```

do:

```cs
if (!App.IsUserLoggedIn)
    MainPage = new LoginPage();
else
    MainPage = new MainPage();
```

Then when LoginPage is done, instead of pop modal, do:

```cs
Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
```

---

NOTE: Adapt as needed, if these are pages inside NavigationPage or AppShell.